# Using bootstrap how to change colour of value button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to chaneg the colour of text using twitter-bootstrap but something is wrong it is not working.
here is my code:

```
<select name="number" '<?=htmlspecialchars($s['number'])?>'td>"
            <option><?=htmlspecialchars($s['number'])?></option>
            <option class="text-cuccess">Tak</option>
            <option class="text-danger">Nie</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `text-success` ? typo? Anyway you can't modify styles of select options.

Comment: bootstrap 4 colors:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/ bootstrap 3 colors:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_typography.asp

Answer (score 0):

```css
.newcolor {
    color:red;
}
.newcolor1{
 color:green;
}
```

```html
<select id="select"  onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
    <option style="color:gray" value="null">select one option</option>
    <option value="1" class="newcolor">one</option>
    <option value="2" class="newcolor">two</option>
    <option value="2" class="newcolor1">two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In your code when the choice is done colour is black.I am trying to do when you make a choice the color will be the same as selected, also i can't use the "value" in my code

Comment: @Przemek, I have modified the answer as per your requirement.

Comment: Ok i will try this with my code, unlucky to me the bootstrap colours don't work...

Comment: Ok I tried your solution but it is not working, offcorse I can choice the colors when I drop down the menu that i see the diferent color of text, but whenn approve the changes and refresh the page the color of my choice is still black, database can not see the colours :(